# Can't open Eclipse E4 .product in Kubuntu14.04

Tags: eclipse, kde-plasma

I recently installed a clean Kubuntu14.04.

In Luna SR1 RCP tried to open a .product file (RMB->Run as->Run configuration) the .product screen appears for half a second then eclipse exited without warning. I tried with and without SWT_GTK3=0 in the eclipse .ini file and this doesn't make a difference.

The same exit without warning occurs when I try to open properties on any level in product explorer.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is the default oxygen-gtk GTK2 theme as discussed here:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/513471/kubuntu-14-04eclipse-adt-crashes-at-button-ok-from-project-properties

Either edit the GTK2 theme config file as outlined above or change System Settings->Application Appearance->GTK->Select a GTK2 There: and change it from oxygen-gtk.